# Why are System.Drawing Rectangle, Point, Size etc mutable structs and not classes?

Tags: c#, .net, design-decisions

Is there a reason Microsoft decided to make these structs?

All three are mutable. I would find them much easier to deal with if they were either immutable, or if they were reference types.

If there are reasons they must be structs, why are they mutable?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how their mutable `struct`ness is causing you issues?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever for example: `foreach (Point r in points) { r.X += 1; }` <-- doesn't work. Basically I _expect_ them to behave like reference types but constantly have to remind myself they aren't.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Why are System.Windows.Point & System.Windows.Vector mutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920080/why-are-system-windows-point-system-windows-vector-mutable)

Comment: @DominicKexel, The question is related, though the accepted answer is only relevant to WPF.

Comment: @Rotem That's why I didn't vote to close :-)

Comment: @Andrew Your code example only fails to work because you are using `foreach`, which boxes the values. It does work in a simple `for` loop. **All three structs are fully mutable**.

Comment: @Rotem Yes, but I guess to me it reads like it should work because `r.X += 1` implies that `r` has reference semantics. Another example is that if I'm allowed to do `r.X += x`, I should be allowed to make `void offsetX(Point p, int xOffset)` work without resorting to `ref`. I can make it work knowing that it's a value type - but why must Microsoft confuse me?

Comment: The fact that `r.X += 1` works only implies that it's a writable field, not that it is a value or reference type. In your method you must use `ref` because otherwise you would be modifying a *copy* of the `Point`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 20):

### Why are they Structs

**Value Semantics**
There is no essential difference between two identical instances of these values. Any `Point` with coordinates, `[2,3]` is equal to any other point with the same coordinates, much like any two `int`s with similar value are equal.
This is in conformance with the design guideline:

> It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>   (integer, double, and so on).

**Performance**

> Value types are cheaper to allocate and deallocate.

There is often requirement to create many instances of these values. Structs cost less to create, and if they are local values, they will be created on the stack, relieving pressure from the GC.

**Size**
Let's consider the size of these values:
`Point` : 8 bytes
`Size`: 8 bytes
`Rectangle`: 16 bytes

For `Point` and `Size`, their size is the same as a reference to a class instance would be in a 64-bit 
system.

Quotes taken from Microsoft's guidelines: [Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229017%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

### Why are they Mutable

These structs are fully mutable. This is done (against the guidelines) for the sake of performance, as it avoids the need to create new values for modification operations.

Regarding the OP's code example in the comments:

```
Point[] points = new Point[] { new Point(0,0), new Point(1,1), new Point(2,2) };

foreach (Point p in points)
{
    p.X += 1; 
}
```

The only reason this `foreach` fails, is because <s>`p` is **boxed** to `object` in order to provide iteration, and you `Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion`,</s> (thanks Rajeev) the iterator returns the data by value, and you would only be making changes to the *copy* of the value.

This works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
{
    points[i].X += 1;
}
```

Comment: @Rotem `Rectangle` violates three out of four of Microsoft's guidelines according to that link.

Comment: @Andrew I agree! But I guess the fact this is logically a value outweighed the other points.

Comment: @Rotem I see your point. Maybe the question should be why are they mutable?

Comment: @JLRishe No, they are mutable. `Rectangle` for instance has an `Offset` method to change its coordinates. The third is that to me a `Rectangle` doesn't represent a single value, but I suppose that's subjective :)

Comment: @Andrew My mistake.  In that case I too find it odd that they are mutable.  I have rescinded my prior comment.

Comment: @Andrew: I really dislike the way that "unified value" guideline is written.  A mutable struct is the data type which best encapsulates a bunch of *independent* but related values *without* encapsulating a collective identity.  The values in an immutable type are much harder to use independently than those of an exposed-field structure, and exposed references to mutable objects cannot avoid encapsulating identity.  The greater the independence of a type's members, the *stronger* the imperative for it being a structure rather than a class.

Comment: @Rotem, I think compiler will translate the foreach loop on Point[] to normal for loop right? Because it does that for int[]. So how come the point will get boxed? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Rajeev I don't understand what you mean. You are definitely not allowed to change the value of the iteration variable in a `foreeach`, e.g. `foreach (int i in myInts) i += 1;`. This results in a compiler error.

Comment: @Rotem, I just have doubt regarding your statement _"The only reason this foreach fails, is because p is boxed to object in order to provide iteration"_ whey there is a need of boxing here?

Comment: @Rajeev I think you're right, it would only get boxed if the container is not generic. I don't know based on what information I wrote the answer, it was over 4 years ago. Nevertheless, the foreach is still not possible because the iterator is returning a copy of the data. I've modified the answer to reflect this information.

Answer (score 2):

### Microsoft doesn't need to define these structures as a class.

These are basically small structures.

- [`Rectangle Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx) stores a set of four integers.
- [`Point Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) represents an ordered pair of integer x- and y-coordinates.
- [`Size Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx) stores an ordered pair of integers.

If these are defined as a `class`, for `Point` structure, same coordinates could refer to different objects in memory. Defining as a `struct`, we know there is no difference between different points with same coordinates. It means they are value types. Value types are almost always cheaper to allocate. Look at their size;

```
Point : 8 bytes
Size: 8 bytes
Rectangle: 16 bytes
```

Who wants to allocate a new memory part every time they create a `Point(1,2)`?