# What are mutable and immutable values in .net

Tags: c#, .net, structure, immutability, msdn

what do means mutable and immutable values in .net?

In msdn:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Struct Design**

**X DO NOT define mutable value types.**

microsoft says
**when a property getter returns a value type, the caller receives a copy. Because the copy is created implicitly, developers might not be aware that they are mutating the copy, and not the original value.** But the Point and Size structures has public read/writable properties. so it is good practice to write structs with properties? properties in a struct should be readonly, writeonly, or no matter? what other immutable values exists?

Comment: Point and Size are a great example of [MS breaking their own guidelines for the sake of performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14192612/14357). There's plenty of question/answers to explain this... [Here's a good one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).